# laravel Session lifetime

Tags: php, laravel, session, lifetime

How to set a single Session lifetime in laravel 5.2 ?

**config/Session**

```
lifetime => 6
```

But,This way will change all the Seesion 
What should I do?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you're trying to do with the session timeout adjustment? Perhaps we can just refresh the session with a job as opposed to trying to alter the session timeout on a per user (i assume) basis.

Comment: when user type an wrong password for 3 times I would not let it to try more, untill to wait over 1 hours

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins` trait out of the box that will help you manage the Throttling.

You can simply implement `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins` on the `AuthController` class.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
class AuthController extends Controller {
    use ..., ThrottlesLogins;
}
```

By default it's 5 attempts with a 1 minute lockout. but you can change these by setting them either in your own trait, or within the constructor function of the controller:

```
$this->maxLoginAttempts = 3;
$this->lockoutTime = 3600; // 1 hour
```